# Prolog - days of the week

Tags: arrays, prolog

I'm new at prolog and it is messing up my head. Could you guys give me a simple example like.. the days of the week! Let's say I have a

```
day(mon, tue, wed, thu, fri).
```

and I wanna know in which day of the week I'm on (assuming on start it'll akways be set as "monday", and I don't even know how to do that also but I think I can figure it out), and I want to set a variable to "tomorrow", (like.. if today is monday I wanna know tomorrow is tuesday)

I know it sounds stupid but I'm used with c and java and this is so hard for me...

Comment: As far as knowing "which day of the week I'm on", that needs a little clarification. What information do you have that you want to use to get to knowing what day of the week? Do you have the current system date? Or nothing and you need to know how to get the system date? Or does your question mean something else?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using libraries, you can also do something like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

ord_weekday(0, mon).
ord_weekday(1, tue).
ord_weekday(2, wed).
ord_weekday(3, thu).
ord_weekday(4, fri).
ord_weekday(5, sat).
ord_weekday(6, sun).

day_next(D, N) :-
    (X+1) mod 7 #= Y,
    ord_weekday(X, D),
    ord_weekday(Y, N).
```

First we mapped 0 to Monday, 1 to Tuesday, and so on; then, we mapped 0 to 1, 1 to 2, ..., 6 to 0.

Now you can query this like that:

```
?- day_next(mon, X).
X = tue.

?- day_next(X, mon).
X = sun.
```

Importantly, you can leave both arguments free variables and enumerate all possible combinations:

```
?- day_next(D, N).
D = mon, N = tue ;
D = tue, N = wed ;
D = wed, N = thu ;
D = thu, N = fri ;
D = fri, N = sat ;
D = sat, N = sun ;
D = sun, N = mon.
```

This gives you the exact same results are [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44015672/1812457). I would prefer the other solution for this particular problem (next day of the week), but there might be something else to be learned from the example here.

Comment: Somewhat baroque, but ok!

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want something like

```
day([mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun]).
```

so that you have a list to work with.

Then monday is `mon` and you can use

```
Tomorrow = mon
```

but if you want to have a general rule for next day, then this is not optimal.

So maybe it would be better to have a predicate `day/2` instead of `day/1`

```
day(mon,tue).
day(tue,wed).
day(wed,thu).
day(thu,fri).
day(fri,sat).
day(sat,sun).
day(sun,mon).
```

Now you can just call `day(Tomorrow,DayAfterThat)` to get, for example, `tue`.

And if you want the list of all the days you can say

```
findall(X,day(X,_),Days)
```

You can modify the rules (eg `day/2`) using `assert/1` and `retract/1`.

Answer (score 2):

An approach similar to what's been presented, but with a different means of determining "tomorrow"...

Probably the most canonical way to lay out valid day of week in Prolog would be with individual facts:

```
% Valid days of the week, in order
day_of_week(mon).
day_of_week(tue).
day_of_week(wed).
day_of_week(thu).
day_of_week(fri).
day_of_week(sat).
day_of_week(sun).
```

Then a query like, `day_of_week(Day)` will succeed for any given valid day of the week `Day`.

To determine the day after a given day, you can use a general circular successor predicate:

```
succ(X, [H|T], S) :-
    succ(X, H, [H|T], S).

succ(X, H, [X], H).
succ(X, _, [X,Y|_], Y).
succ(X, H, [_|T], S) :-
    succ(X, H, T, S).
```

So determining the next day would be:

```
day_after(Day, NextDay) :-
    % List valid days of the week in order
    findall(DayOfWeek, day_of_week(DayOfWeek), DaysOfWeek),
    succ(Day, DaysOfWeek, NextDay).  % NextDay is successor to Day
```

Comment: If you don't mind CLP(FD) you can also map each day to an integer (say `day_of_week(0, mon). day_of_week(1, tue).` and so on) and then use modulo arithmetic to map 0 to 1, 1 to 2, ..., and 6 to 0.

Comment: @Boris I "don't mind" CLP(FD). :) Definitely an interesting option in this case.

Comment: OK, it was just a few lines of code so there is yet another answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This may help you to get started:

```
days(mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun).

tomorrow(X,Y) :- days(|Z), tomorrow(X,Y,Z).

tomorrow(X,Y,[X,Y|_]).
tomorrow(X,Y,[_|Z]) :- tomorrow(X,Y,Z).

?- tomorrow(X,tue), write(X), nl.
```

It writes out `mon`.

Comment: Since I gave you a -1: your solution might be technically correct but it is just bad advice on how to solve this question in particular or how to use Prolog in general. See [the answer by @TomasBy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44015672/1812457) for a very clean and straight-forward solution (using the `day/2` table).

Comment: @Boris - I started with the OP's "Let's say I have a" prolog code and built it from that. It's certainly not the way I would have tackled this. Tomas's answer is certainly the right way to go.

Comment: Your `tomorrow/3` is not a bad idea in general, it just solves a different problem altogether (in my opinion)....

Comment: Which Prolog allows to write `days(|Z)` ? Never seen this syntax.

Comment: @CapelliC - Strawberry Prolog.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes the canonical answer—based on  [`append/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append):

```
today_tomorrow(T0, T1) :-
   Days = [mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun,mon],
   append(_, [T0,T1|_], Days).
```

Let's ask the *most general query*!

```
?- today_tomorrow(X, Y).
   X = mon, Y = tue
;  X = tue, Y = wed
;  X = wed, Y = thu
;  X = thu, Y = fri
;  X = fri, Y = sat
;  X = sat, Y = sun
;  X = sun, Y = mon
;  false.                   % no more solutions
```

Answer (score -1):

#### program

```
  ([user]) .

  %%%% database-style prolog program .
  %%% for day  , tomorrow , yesterday .

  day( day( sk( 10'7 ) , pk( 36'sun ) , nm( 'sunday' )      , next( 36'mon ) ) ) .
  day( day( sk( 10'6 ) , pk( 36'sat ) , nm( 'saturday' )    , next( 36'sun ) ) ) .
  day( day( sk( 10'5 ) , pk( 36'fri ) , nm( 'friday' )      , next( 36'sat ) ) ) .
  day( day( sk( 10'4 ) , pk( 36'thu ) , nm( 'thursday' )    , next( 36'fri ) ) ) .
  day( day( sk( 10'3 ) , pk( 36'wed ) , nm( 'wednesday' )   , next( 36'thu ) ) ) .
  day( day( sk( 10'2 ) , pk( 36'tue ) , nm( 'tuesday' )     , next( 36'wed ) ) ) .
  day( day( sk( 10'1 ) , pk( 36'mon ) , nm( 'monday' )      , next( 36'tue ) ) ) .

  tomorrow( tomorrow( day( _tomorrow_ ) )  , today( day( _today_ ) ) )
  :-
  (
     _today_ = ( day( sk( _ ) , pk( _ ) , nm( _ ) , next( _next_ ) ) ) ,
     _tomorrow_ = ( day( sk( _ ) , pk( _next_ ) , nm( _ ) , next( _ ) ) ) ,

     day( _today_ ) , 
     day( _tomorrow_ )
  ) .

  yesterday( yesterday( day( _yesterday_ ) )  , today( day( _today_ ) ) )
  :-
  (
     tomorrow( tomorrow( day( _today_ ) ) , today( day( _yesterday_ ) ) )
  ) .

  %%% legend

  %%    pk --- primary key
  %%    sk --- secondary (sort) key
  %%    nm --- name 
  %%    10'2 --- a number whereby each digit has 10 possibilities ( [0-9] )
  %%    16'ff --- a number whereby each digit has 16 possibilities ( [0-9,a-f] )
  %%    36'mon --- a number whereby each digit has 36 possibilities ( [0-9,a-z] )
```

#### example usage

```
  %%%% example usage


  %% query for all day

  ?- day( DAY ) .

  %@ DAY = day(sk(7),pk(37391),nm(sunday),next(29399)) ? ;
  %@ DAY = day(sk(6),pk(36677),nm(saturday),next(37391)) ? ;
  %@ DAY = day(sk(5),pk(20430),nm(friday),next(36677)) ? ;
  %@ DAY = day(sk(4),pk(38226),nm(thursday),next(20430)) ? ;
  %@ DAY = day(sk(3),pk(41989),nm(wednesday),next(38226)) ? ;
  %@ DAY = day(sk(2),pk(38678),nm(tuesday),next(41989)) ? ;
  %@ DAY = day(sk(1),pk(29399),nm(monday),next(38678))

  %% query for all day , sorted

  ?- setof( _day_ , day( _day_ ) , VECTOR ) .

  %@ VECTOR =
  %@ [
  %@    day(sk(1),pk(29399),nm(monday),next(38678)) ,
  %@    day(sk(2),pk(38678),nm(tuesday),next(41989)) ,
  %@    day(sk(3),pk(41989),nm(wednesday),next(38226)) ,
  %@    day(sk(4),pk(38226),nm(thursday),next(20430)) ,
  %@    day(sk(5),pk(20430),nm(friday),next(36677)) ,
  %@    day(sk(6),pk(36677),nm(saturday),next(37391)) ,
  %@    day(sk(7),pk(37391),nm(sunday),next(29399))
  %@ ]

  %% query for all day , sorted

  ?- use_module( library( lists ) ) .   % for ``member`` .
  ?- setof( _day_ , day( _day_ ) , _vector_ ) , member( DAY , _vector_ ) .

  %@ DAY = day(sk(1),pk(29399),nm(monday),next(38678)) ? ;
  %@ DAY = day(sk(2),pk(38678),nm(tuesday),next(41989)) ? ;
  %@ DAY = day(sk(3),pk(41989),nm(wednesday),next(38226)) ? ;
  %@ DAY = day(sk(4),pk(38226),nm(thursday),next(20430)) ? ;
  %@ DAY = day(sk(5),pk(20430),nm(friday),next(36677)) ? ;
  %@ DAY = day(sk(6),pk(36677),nm(saturday),next(37391)) ? ;
  %@ DAY = day(sk(7),pk(37391),nm(sunday),next(29399)) ? ;

  %% query for all yesterday 

  ?-
  _query_ =
  (
     yesterday( yesterday( day( _yesterday_ ) ) , today( day( _today_ ) ) )
  )
  , 
  setof( [ _yesterday_ , _today_ ]  , _query_ , VECTOR )
  .

  %@ VECTOR =
  %@ [
  %@    [  day(sk(1),pk(29399),nm(monday),next(38678)) ,     day(sk(2),pk(38678),nm(tuesday),next(41989))  ] ,
  %@    [  day(sk(2),pk(38678),nm(tuesday),next(41989)) ,    day(sk(3),pk(41989),nm(wednesday),next(38226))] ,
  %@    [  day(sk(3),pk(41989),nm(wednesday),next(38226)) ,  day(sk(4),pk(38226),nm(thursday),next(20430)) ] ,
  %@    [  day(sk(4),pk(38226),nm(thursday),next(20430)) ,   day(sk(5),pk(20430),nm(friday),next(36677))   ] ,
  %@    [  day(sk(5),pk(20430),nm(friday),next(36677)) ,     day(sk(6),pk(36677),nm(saturday),next(37391)) ] ,
  %@    [  day(sk(6),pk(36677),nm(saturday),next(37391)) ,   day(sk(7),pk(37391),nm(sunday),next(29399))   ] ,
  %@    [  day(sk(7),pk(37391),nm(sunday),next(29399)) ,     day(sk(1),pk(29399),nm(monday),next(38678))   ]
  %@ ]


  %% query for all tomorrow  .
  % format results as a json-style map .

  ?-
  _query_ =
  (
     tomorrow( tomorrow( day( _tomorrow_ ) ) , today( day( _today_ ) ) )
     ,
     _tomorrow_ = day( _ , _ , nm( _nm_tomorrow_ ) , _ )
     ,
     _today_ = day( _ , _ , nm( _nm_today_ ) , _ )
  )
  ,
  _each_ =
  (
     { tommorrow: _nm_tomorrow_ , today: _nm_today_ }
  )
  ,
  setof( _each_ , _query_ , VECTOR )
  .

  %@ VECTOR = [{tommorrow:friday,today:thursday}] ? ;
  %@ VECTOR = [{tommorrow:monday,today:sunday}] ? ;
  %@ VECTOR = [{tommorrow:saturday,today:friday}] ? ;
  %@ VECTOR = [{tommorrow:sunday,today:saturday}] ? ;
  %@ VECTOR = [{tommorrow:thursday,today:wednesday}] ? ;
  %@ VECTOR = [{tommorrow:tuesday,today:monday}] ? ;
  %@ VECTOR = [{tommorrow:wednesday,today:tuesday}]

  %% query for the day named monday

  ?-
  _nm_ =  'monday'
  ,
  _day_ = day( sk( _sk_ ) , pk( _pk_ ) , nm( _nm_ ) , _etc_ )
  ,
  setof( _day_ , day( _day_ ) , VECTOR )
  .

  %@ VECTOR =
  %@ [
  %@    day(sk(1),pk(29399),nm(monday),next(38678))
  %@ ]

  %% query for the today of the tomorrow named monday

  ?-
  _today_ = day( _ , _ , nm( _nm_today_ ) , _ )
  ,
  _tomorrow_ = day( _ , _ , nm( _nm_tomorrow_ ) , _ )
  ,
  _nm_tomorrow_ = 'monday'
  ,
  _query_ = tomorrow( tomorrow( day( _tomorrow_ ) ) , today( day( _today_ ) ) )
  ,
  _each_ = { tomorrow: _nm_tomorrow_ , today: _nm_today_ }
  ,
  setof( _each_ , _query_ , VECTOR )
  .

  %@ VECTOR =
  %@ [
  %@    { tomorrow: monday , today: sunday }
  %@ ]
```